# GitAhead - Can you please add an "Amend" checkbox when committing?

Tags: gitahead

Many other popular clients have this and I use it quite often.

If this already exists in the app (which I can't find) then it needs to be made much more visible. A checkbox right next to the commit button.

Comment: You will have better luck making a feature request [in the GitHub repository](https://github.com/gitahead/gitahead/issues) than on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ah ok, it's just that the app itself directs people here :/ Thanks.